# How to stream a M3U file on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios, music, streaming, playlist

I'm managing a lot of favourite internet radio stations in a m3u file that is stored on my Dropbox to use it on several devices, but I have problems to play this on my iOS device.

So far, I was unable to find any app that does the job for me. On Android there are many apps like Total Commander that can play m3u files with radio streams.

Here is an example content of such a m3u file:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,Epic Sounds FM
http://stream3.laut.fm:8080/epicsoundsfm
```

Is there any way to play this file without jailbreaking the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GSE SMART IPTV app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/gse-smart-iptv/id1028734023) is recommended to playback M3U streams on iOS devices.

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted...the description says it supports M3U files.

Comment: Thank you so much, works like charm. :) Welcome to the stack exchange space, btw.